# css how to merge one header cell in one cell

Tags: css, html-table, header

I have the following header

[image]

I have the following jsp

```
<table id="datos" class="tablainforme compact">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px;text-align:center;" rowspan="3" >Centro</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" rowspan="3">Nombre</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" rowspan="3">Matricula</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px"rowspan="3">Fecha</th>
                    <th  style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" rowspan="3">Principio</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" rowspan="3">Fin</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" rowspan="3">Diferencia</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5">7 a 15</th>
                    <th  colspan="5"> 15 a 23</th>
                    <th  colspan="5">23 a 7</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>


                    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Locomotoras</th>
                    <th  colspan="2">Personal</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Incidencias</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Locomotoras</th>
                    <th  colspan="2">Personal</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" >Incidencias</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Locomotoras</th>
                    <th  colspan="2">Personal</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Incidencias</th>

                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px" >&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-top:0px">&nbsp</th>
                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>

                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>
                    <th>&nbsp</th>

                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>
                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>
                    <th>Asig.</th>
                    <th>Desa.</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

I want to merge the cell Incidencias in one cell . I tried rowspan=2 but it doesn't work.

Also I tried rowspan=3. This merge the cell Incidencias in one but it isn't right.

[image]

How can I do a rowspan=2 of cell Incidencias

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct..! because, if you use

```html
<th  rowspan="3">Incidencias</th>
```

then it reflect on the childs of "Locomotoras" by shifting one position right which is not good.

so please use rowspan="2" only.
again if your requirement is something else then please try to give us format like you want to see as an output.